# what does frame.setLayout(null)do?(frame is a JFrame)

Tags: java, swing

I have seen this in a slide but I couldn't get that when and why we use this?

Answer (score 3):

null layout means absolute positioning - you have to do all the work in your code.  No layout manager to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you start by reading the [Swing tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html)? There is a section that explains all about Layout Management as well as well what "absolute positioning" is. It also explains when you would use abolute positioning versus using a layout manager.

Generally the only time you would use it is when you need to support drag components to a random position.

The tutorial also has lots of other basic examples of using Swing components.

Comment: camickr, welcome.  Are you still hitting the Sun Java Forum as well?

Comment: Yes, I browse a few different forums just to see if the questions are any different.